# REST API Debugging Tool

Tags: debugging, rest

I am looking for a windows tool for sending POST requests to a url, for debugging a new application I am working on. Preferably an open source or free software. What do you all use to debug your applications. The tool should be a GUI tool. Is there such a tool, for free, for windows 7, available. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com)

Comment: How do I set post values like a=1 b=2 in fiddler. I am in the request builder

Comment: In the request body you set your parameters just as you would a query string: a=1&b=2&c=3 etc

Comment: I have it set to https://api.site.net/api/method/myToken and the request body is card=1234. I get the error "card is not set". I wrote the code, so I know that means that the card variable is not set. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Did you set the Method of the request to POST?

Comment: I would say that yes, you're doing it right, however I obviously cannot explain why you're getting that error.

Comment: Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded was the issue

Answer (score 3):

I suggest Dev HTTP Client, it's a chrome plugin and has a very simple but complete interface. [DHC by Restlet Download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm)

[image: Dev HTTP Client]

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is free, and lets you build http requests.

Answer (score 1):

I use Fiddler for doing fairly quick and user friendly debugging.
I use Telnet for super quick debugging from a command line (you must know your HTTP protocol fairly well)
I use SoapUI when I have a REST API with a WSDL or WADL.  (This also is a decent testing program)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tool to create comprehensive tests, You can try out Jmeter from Apache , its free. All you need is JRE to be installed.

Jmeter works out well building up HTTP requests and you can also use its Validation functions to have simple asserts on the HTTP response.